# Compile error while setting imageAnalysis.setAnalyzer()

Tags: android, android-camerax

I'm creating a tool to capture every frame from preview using cameraX (for face recognition purpose)

I found that using ImageAnalysis was the way to go.

Until I tried using the code as recommended :

```
val imageAnalysisConfig = ImageAnalysisConfig.Builder()
            .setTargetResolution(Size(1280, 720))
            .setImageReaderMode(ImageAnalysis.ImageReaderMode.ACQUIRE_LATEST_IMAGE)
            .build()
        val imageAnalysis = ImageAnalysis(imageAnalysisConfig)

        imageAnalysis.setAnalyzer({ image: ImageProxy, rotationDegrees: Int ->
            viewModel.onAnalyzeImage(image)
        })
```

To which I get the following compile error on setAnalyser method :

```
None of the following function can be called with the arguments supplied
setAnalyser((command : Runnable!) -> Unit,  (image: ImageProxy!, rotationDegrees: Int) -> Unit)
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I was also facing the same issue today, so , found that there is one missing parameter which is `Executor` which we need to pass otherwise same compilation error comes.

As as I worked with `AsyncTasks` in my past, I recognized that for doing tasks in multiple threads in `AsyncTasks`, we need to use its static method `executeOnExecutor()` which takes an `Executor` as its parameter, so I used the same parameter i.e. I used `AsyncTask.THREAD_POOL_EXECUTOR` as first parameter in `setAnalyser()` method. And it worked like a charm!! After putting this as first parameter you need to perform some minor changes in your previous code.

### Like this

```
 imageAnalysis.setAnalyzer(AsyncTask.THREAD_POOL_EXECUTOR,
 object : ImageAnalysis.Analyzer {    // changes to be done in this line
                    override fun analyze(imageProxy: ImageProxy, rotationDegrees: Int) {
                        val image = FirebaseVisionImage.fromMediaImage(
                                imageProxy.image!!, getFirebaseRotation(rotationDegrees)
                        )
        
                        if (processingBarcode.get() ||
                                !lifecycle.currentState.isAtLeast(Lifecycle.State.RESUMED)) {
                            return
                        }
    ..................
    .............
    .......BLA BLA BLA
    }
```

Try it and tell me if this approach works with your use case.

## EDIT

If you don't like `AsyncTask`, then I have found an alternative for getting an `Executor` instance without using `AsyncTask.THREAD_POOL_EXECUTOR`.

You can use `Executors.newFixedThreadPool(n)`, to get an `Executor` instance.
Here, n stands for the number of threads you want to create in the thread pool.It varies depending upon your use-case.

Tell me if it worked for you.

Comment: Thanks, but maybe AsyncTask not the best solution for this?

Comment: Yeah, it might not be the best solution @Kostya, but I don't know any other way other than AsyncTask.THREAD_POOL_EXECUTOR which returns an Executor instance. I have also searched the web for any solution which provides an Executor instance, but did not succeed in finding it till now

Comment: I have updated the answer with a new alternative other than `AsyncTask`. Do check it out if you want @KostyaBakay

Answer (score 0):

You can also find the implementation in the official CameraX sample app:
[CameraFragment.kt](https://github.com/android/camera-samples/blob/master/CameraXBasic/app/src/main/java/com/android/example/cameraxbasic/fragments/CameraFragment.kt).

The part which you need is this:

```
// Executor field
private lateinit var analysisExecutor: Executor

// in onCreate()
analysisExecutor = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor()

// after initializing imageAnalysis
imageAnalysis.setAnalyzer(analysisExecutor, ImageAnalysis.Analyzer {
    // TODO analyze
})
```

If you're wondering whether to use `Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor()`, `Executors.newFixedThreadPool(n)` or something else, take a look at the [Executors documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/concurrent/Executors).